# C++ variable scope

Tags: c++, private-members

```
// declare a class with private variable “int * _a”

// declare a function of this class,  foo()

Void foo() {

int * _a; // 1. Does this re-declaration then make _a equal to an unknown value?
          // 2. Does a go out of scope after foo() returns?

}
```

Comment: Please post code that at least compiles. As written, not only is the code broken, but foo is not a member function of any class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 1. Does this re-declaration then make `_a` equal to an unknown value?

No.  This isn't a "re-declaration."  It is a declaration of a local variable named `_a`.  It is uninitialized.

It has no relation whatsoever to the class member variable `_a`.  After the declaration of the local `_a`, you cannot access the member variable `_a` anymore using `_a` (because `_a` refers to the local variable!), but you can refer to it using `this->_a`.

> 1. Does a go out of scope after `foo()` returns?

Yes.  Local variables go out of scope when the scope in which they are declared ends (that's what "going out of scope" comes from).

Answer (score 1):

This is what is so-called **shadowing**. `foo()`'s local pointer `_a` shadows the class' member pointer of the same name. Given that `foo()` is a member of the class, any reference to `_a` would resolve to the local pointer. Moreover, as any scoped variable this pointer will automatically destroy itself when it goes out of scope. The member pointer, needless to say, will stay alive for as long as its owning instance is alive.

To access the member data you'd have to say `this->_a`.